# Tried to do a chronometer, but failed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do the most simple chronometer, just one number that keeps counting infinite. Please keep in mind I am trying to correct my ***own code***, do refrain from answering with "this post is a duplicate of ...", because I probably won't understand other examples. For some reason my code doesn't work, please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #screen {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 500px;
    }

    #chronometer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 300px;
    font-size: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="screen">
        <div id="chronometer"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var chronometer = setInterval(increaseChronometer, 1000);
    function increaseChronometer () {
        var chronometerNumber = 1;
        document.getElementById("chronometer").innerHTML = chronometerNumber;
        chronometerNumber++;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ask a question explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the "chronometerNumber" variable inside the function, so it gets created and initialized to "1" every time you invoke the function.

Just move the line "var chronometerNumber=1" outside the function and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think i got it !

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #screen {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 500px;
    }

    #chronometer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 300px;
    font-size: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="screen">
        <div id="chronometer"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var chronometerNumber = 1;
    var chronometer = setInterval(  function increaseChronometer () {
    document.getElementById("chronometer").innerHTML = chronometerNumber;
    chronometerNumber++;
    }, 1000); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the reference of the `setInterval (){}` function is written that you have to make anonimus function which will be called every time after timeout, and I did it i put your function inside the `setInterval function` also i move your `var chronometerNumber = 1;` declaration outside the function because if it is in there every time the function is called your counter will start from one again and again and so on and you will see only one every time. I home i was helpful and sorry for the english.